# OAuth 2.0 sample error when accessing Google API

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

With the open source project [google-api-ruby-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/), I'm trying to run the OAuth 2.0 sample calendar.rb, which will access Google Calendar API.
I've created client ID in Google API console, and fill the client ID and the secret in the ruby script.

However, after I run the ruby script

```
ruby calendar.rb
```

and then open http://localhost:4567, the browser return error information from Google to me:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:4567/oauth2callback did not match a     registered redirect URI
```

I checked the information in the Google API console:

```
Redirect URIs:  https://localhost/oauth2callback
JavaScript origins: https://localhost
```

What's the problem and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also provide the port number in the redirect and Javascript URI's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect URI has to match exactly. You can't omit anything. You've dropped the port number. But mismatching a trailing slash or really anything else will cause this error. It has to be an exact, character-for-character match.

The two values should be:

Redirect URIs: `https://localhost:4567/oauth2callback`

JavaScript origins: `https://localhost:4567`

Comment: I just got started on the Calendar API and am using CLI to create the google-api.yaml file as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate but I am getting the same error when running this command. It automatically opens the browser and shows the error "400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:12736/ did not match a registered redirect URI" . DO I have to explicitly put the redirect URI somewhere? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the port numbers and it worked fine.

However, the Redirect URI was: http://localhost/oauth2callback

I had this example working last night.

Comment: Ports are required. Google docs: "Register the origins where your app is allowed to access the Google APIs. The origin is the unique combination of protocol, hostname, and port. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on different protocols, domains or subdomains. Wildcards are not allowed."

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Everything was matching, URL was correct, consent page was filled, but I had to generate a new Client ID three times. It started working just on the third time. I don't know the reason. I didn't change anything in configuration or code, it just started working with the third Client ID and Client Secret.