# Use google-api-ruby-client gem have redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want use [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings) API in rails.

It says should include an Authorization header.(use oauth2)

So I use `google-api-ruby-client` this lib like below.
I write below code by [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2).

```
@client = Google::APIClient.new
@client.authorization.client_id = CONSUMER_KEY
@client.authorization.client_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
@client.authorization.scope = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/'
@client.authorization.redirect_uri = "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port.to_s}
                                     /google_app/oauth2callback"

redirect_to @client.authorization.authorization_uri.to_s
```

But it cause redirect_uri_mismatch error.
I don't know whether my usage is correct.

Note:
Before use this API, I have logined with Google Openid successfully.

Answer (score 0):

might be a duplicate of [OAuth 2.0 sample error when accessing Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290182/oauth-2-0-sample-error-when-accessing-google-api)

the problem there is, that the javascript is missing the port-number.